# Make a distinct select in SQL,selecting all "categoria" except one distincted

Tags: mysql, distinct

[image]

i want to select "categoria",idjogo where idjogo=NULL, except the hentai. the hentai i want to select is the one where idjogo=100;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE idjogo <=> IF(categoria='hentai',100,NULL)
```